# Socket.IO Broadcast emit not working how to fix it ,

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Hey there i'm trying to send message to everyone connected to the server that a new user is connected except the new user connect so i'm using socket.broadcast.emit() but it doesn't fire up in browser console

my code :

```
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')


const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname,'../public')

app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    
    console.log('New web socket connection')
   
    socket.emit('welcome',"Welcome !")

    socket.broadcast.emit('message','A new user has joined !')

  

    socket.on('sendMessage',(message)=>{
        io.emit('messageSent',message)
    })

})


server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('Server is up on 3000')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send to ***everyone*** (including yourself) with:

```
io.emit(...)
```

Or to ***everyone else*** (but not yourself - i.e. not `socket`) with:

```
socket.broadcast.emit(...)
```